# Install newest bumblebee nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, bumblebee

I am using 13.04 and I followed this guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

But my drivers are a little bit dated, they only support OpenGL 4.0. How can I find out what version I am running and how can I update to a newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in `/var/log/syslog`  search for `NVRM`. This will give you details about the NVIDIA driver.

As of Aug 10 2013 `nvidia-common` (installed as part of the bumblebee install) was 304.88

Newer drivers are in testing.